Include custom data fields in useSession
I'm using Next-Auth 4 in NextJS 14 App Router.
I would like to display the entire user info on frontend such as: email, name.
However the useSession() hook only returns email.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?
Here is my code:
/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const handler = NextAuth({
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    //debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    callbacks: {},
    pages: {
        signIn: "/account/login",
    },
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. "Sign in with...")
            name: "Credentials",
            // `credentials` is used to generate a form on the sign in page.
            // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
            // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
            // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
            credentials: {
                username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials: any) {
                const { username, password } = credentials;
                try {
                    // Look up user by email
                    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                        where: {
                            email: username || "",
                        },
                    });

                    // If user not found or password does not match, return null
                    if (
                        !user ||
                        !(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))
                    ) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    // Generate JWT token
                    const token = jwt.sign(
                        {
                            id: user.id,
                            email: user.email,
                            firstName: user.firstName,
                            lastName: user.lastName,
                            role: user.roleId,
                        }, // Payload
                        "secret", // JWT secret
                        { expiresIn: "30d" } // Token expiration time
                    );

                    // Return user data along with token
                    return {
                        id: user.id,
                        email: user.email,
                        firstName: user.firstName,
                        lastName: user.lastName,
                        role: user.roleId,
                        token,
                    };
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Login error:", error);
                    return null;
                } finally {
                    await prisma.$disconnect();
                }
            },
            callbacks: {
                async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any; user: any }) {
                    // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
                    console.log('jwt user',user);
                    if (user) {
                        token.firstName = user.firstName;
                    }
                    return token;
                },
                async session({
                    session,
                    token,
                    user,
                }: {
                    session: any;
                    token: any;
                    user: any;
                }) {
                    // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
                    console.log('session user',user);
                    session.firstName = token.firstName;
                    return session;
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

Furthermore, I have a Type error in the authorize() function as well
Type '(credentials: any) => Promise<{ id: number; email: string; firstName: string; lastName: string; role: number; token: string; } | null>' is not assignable to type '(credentials: Record<"username" | "password", string> | undefined, req: Pick<RequestInternal, "query" | "body" | "headers" | "method">) => Awaitable<...>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ id: number; email: string; firstName: string; lastName: string; role: number; token: string; } | null>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<User | null>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ id: number; email: string; firstName: string; lastName: string; role: number; token: string; } | null>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<User | null>'.
      Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
        Type '<TResult1 = { id: number; email: string; firstName: string; lastName: string; role: number; token: string; } | null, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: { id: number; email: string; firstName: string; lastName: string; role: number; token: string; } | null) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined, on...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = User | null, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: User | null) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.
          Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
            Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
              Type '{ id: number; email: string; firstName: string; lastName: string; role: number; token: string; } | null' is not assignable to type 'User | null'.
                Type '{ id: number; email: string; firstName: string; lastName: string; role: number; token: string; }' is not assignable to type 'User'.
                  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
                    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

I did follow this topic I need help sending custom information to session.user object using next-auth but it does not solve my issue.
